# ¿Cómo convertir una cadena en un DATETIME?

Tags: sql-server, datetime

**Necesito convertir un varchar a fecha valida en sql server.**

```
DECLARE @SDATE AS VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Viernes, 04 Agosto 2017, 07:11:31.240 p.m.';
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, @SDATE)
PRINT(@SDATE)`
```

Mensaje:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Conversion failed when converting date >and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no es un formato del todo amigable para la rutina [`CONVERT()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql), se me ocurre hacer un poco de recorte sobre el string para obtener cada dato, algo así:

```
DECLARE @SDATE AS VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Viernes, 04 Agosto 2017, 07:11:31.240 p.m.';

DECLARE @HORA  AS NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @FECHA AS NVARCHAR(255)

SELECT @FECHA = REPLACE(@SDATE, ',', '.')
SELECT @FECHA = LEFT(@FECHA, LEN(@FECHA) - 5)
SELECT @HORA  = PARSENAME(@FECHA,2) + '.' + PARSENAME(@FECHA,1)

SELECT @FECHA = REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(PARSENAME(@FECHA,3))), ' ', '.')
SELECT @FECHA = PARSENAME(@FECHA,1) + CASE PARSENAME(@FECHA,2) 
                                    WHEN 'Enero'      THEN '01'
                                    WHEN 'Febrero'    THEN '02'
                                    WHEN 'Marzo'      THEN '03'
                                    WHEN 'Abril'      THEN '04'
                                    WHEN 'Mayo'       THEN '05'
                                    WHEN 'Junio'      THEN '06'
                                    WHEN 'Julio'      THEN '07'
                                    WHEN 'Agosto'     THEN '08'
                                    WHEN 'Septiembre' THEN '09'
                                    WHEN 'Octubre'    THEN '10'
                                    WHEN 'Noviembre'  THEN '11'
                                    WHEN 'Diciembre'  THEN '12'
                              END + PARSENAME(@FECHA,3)

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, @FECHA + @HORA)
```

Importante: el código hace uso de la función [`PARSENAME()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql) que se encuentra disponible a partir de Sql Server 2012, para versiones anteriores habría que buscar otra forma de resolver el problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Es correcto el ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

A partir de SQL Server 2012, tienes la opción de usar [`TRY_PARSE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql) o [`PARSE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parse-transact-sql) que permiten convertir a partir una cadena a un determinado tipo.

---

Para tu problema, solo sería necesario realizar:

```
SELECT TRY_PARSE(REPLACE(
                            REPLACE(
                                       'Viernes, 04 Agosto 2017, 07:11:31.240 p.m.'
                                      ,'p.m.'
                                      ,'PM'
                                   )
                           ,'a.m.'
                           ,'AM'
                        ) AS DATETIME USING 'es-PE')
   ,PARSE(REPLACE(
                     REPLACE(
                                'Viernes, 04 Agosto 2017, 07:11:31.240 p.m.'
                               ,'p.m.'
                               ,'PM'
                            )
                    ,'a.m.'
                    ,'AM'
                 ) AS DATETIME USING 'es-PE');
```

> ```
> +-------------------------+-------------------------+
> | 2017-08-04 19:11:31.240 | 2017-08-04 19:11:31.240 |
> +-------------------------+-------------------------+
> ```

Lo que hago primero es reemplazar las siglas de `a.m.` a `AM` y `p.m.` a `PM`.

---

La diferencia entre [`TRY_PARSE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql) y [`PARSE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parse-transact-sql) es que el primero en caso no pueda convertir arrojará `NULL` (nulo) como resultado y el segundo arrojará un error.

Por ejemplo:

**TRY_PARSE:**

```
SELECT TRY_PARSE('Viernes, 04 AAgosto 2017' AS DATETIME USING 'es-PE')
```

> ```
> +------+
> | NULL |
> +------+
> ```

**PARSE:**

```
SELECT PARSE('Viernes, 04 AAgosto 2017' AS DATETIME USING 'es-PE');
```

> Error converting string value 'Viernes, 04 AAgosto 2017' into data
>   type datetime using culture 'es-PE'.

---

**Referencia:**

- [PARSE (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parse-transact-sql)
- [TRY_PARSE (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql)